# Inventory system multiple tables and recipes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice in PHP and extremely new to databases, so forgive me if this is a stupid question:

I've built an inventory system in PHP/MySQL  that allows someone to (among other things) add raw materials to a table, that has "Price_Per_Pound_In_Dollars" and "Pounds_In_Stock" columns. As it stands, updating the "Pounds-In-Stock" column for a raw material must be done manually, one-at-a-time via a form.

I'm now wanting to add another database for recipes that contains the steps needed for making a product, so that the "Pounds_In_Stock" column can be updated for multiple raws at once.  Please see the image below.

[image]

Basically someone would go to a form, pick a product from a drop down menu (populated with recipe names by doing a `mysqli_query`), enter the number of gallons they want to make and press submit.

The rows in the recipe table have the figures needed for making a gallon of that product, so all of the numbers in the table would be multiplied by the number that was entered into the form.

So, if someone were to choose "Recipe Name 1" and entered "2" into the gallons input box. It would multiply the "Pounds_Needed_Per_Gallon" by 2 and put that info into a `mysqli_query` to remove it from the correct raw "Pounds_In_Stock" column in the "Raws" table. (If that makes sense).

**Now my question:**

Is it possible to do this dynamically? Am I approaching this the wrong way? I know I can get the result I want by hard coding the values for each recipe in a PHP document and linking to it via the "action =" on the form page, but this seems like an exceedingly inelegant way of doing things. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to  do this with MySQL.

**Form Issue:**

I created a bare-bones form that should include the table names in a drop-down menu (so that a recipe table can be selected). But I can't seem to get the table names to echo out in the drop down. I know the while loop is working correctly, since there are three options in the drop-down menu, which corresponds to the number of tables in the database, the only problem is that they're blank. Please see the image and code below. I looked over my code a few times, but can't see where I made a mistake. Any ideas?

```
<?php

//Prepare MySQL Query.
$Product_Menu_Query ="SHOW TABLES"; 
$Run_Product_Menu_Query = mysqli_query($Connect, $Product_Menu_Query);
?>


<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <span>Recipe Name:</span><br>
    <select name="recipe">

        <?php  //Populates dropdown with Product_Name from database. 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Run_Product_Menu_Query)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . '</option>';
        }

    ?>
     </select><br><br>
    <span>Gallons:</span><br>
    <input type="number" name="gallons"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Screenshot of form:**

[image]

Comment: Are we allowed to know what kind of products we're talking about?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, could you please clarify what you mean? I can tell you that all of the products/recipes will be liquids (hence, why there is only a gallon option). I can go into more detail if you feel it is needed, and I can also assure you that this inventory system isn't for anything nefarious. :)

Comment: I'm hoping it's beer. Is that nefarious?

Comment: Nope it isn't for beer (unfortunately). :)

Comment: this line : `echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' . '</option>';` is causing the option text to be empty as you didn't put any text between option tags. it should probably be `echo "<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>";`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you would have something like this (change your table names and fields accordingly to your database actual field and table names):

```
$recipeName = $_POST['recipe'];
$gallons = $_POST['gallons'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT raws.id as rawId, (recipe.pounds_needed_per_gallon * ?) as gallons
  FROM RecipeName recipe
  JOIN Raws raws on recipe.raw_id=raws.raw_id
  WHERE raws.raw_name = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ds", $gallons, $recipeName);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($rawId, $gallonsNeeded);
$stmt->close();

mysqli_query("UPDATE Raws set pounds_in_stock = (pounds_in_stock - $gallonsNeeded) where id = $rawId");
```

**EDIT**: I see you need more help with debugging. You should check the values obtained through the queries (i.e. rawId and gallonsNeeded) and echo out errors, but as i don't have your entire code base I cannot tell exactly what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi Joe,
Thanks so much for your response, I'll test the code out later today and update you from there. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Joe,
I went to test your code but ran into a form related problem. I updated my question with the related code, would you mind taking a look? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again Joe. All of my columns are named as they are in the picture. My tables however, are named "Raws" and "Recipe1 and are in the same database. Unfortunately the code you provided doesn't seem to be updating the "Raws" table. Do you have any ideas why that may be?

Comment: You're going to have to provide me with some more info. Errors thrown by the database, etc.

Comment: Hi Joe, I added `or die (mysqli_error());` to the code you provided, but it isn't returning any errors. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Joe,

Thanks again for the response, I'll try that later today when I get back to my main machine.  Just out of curiosity, when you say you "don't have my entire code base", what exactly are you missing? I'm just testing this code on my local machine via MAMP,  so the only files that exist are the form and a "submit" file that contains the code you provided.

Comment: This is going well beyond the scope of the initial question, you can't ask a question then edit it to be two questions. My mail is in my profile if you want to contact me to help you resolve the second issue, meanwhile please consider accepting the answer if it resolved the original problem.

Comment: Hi Joe, fair enough. I didn't mean to keep expanding the scope of this question (I apologize for that). I'll accept you're answer on the (the fairly safe) presumption that I'm doing something incorrectly on my end, because this certainly seems like it should work. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Hi Joe, just so you know, your email actually isn't visible in  your profile. I suspect your account is set up much like mine, in the sense that your email is only displayed to yourself when you're logged in.

Comment: Hi Joe, I made my email visible on my profile page, would you mind shooting me over a quick email when you get a chance? Thanks!